# Check if div is scrolled to bottom, leave alone if not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I recently developed a live online chat room. I have everything working and secure but I want the div that the messages are stored in to autoscroll to the bottom. I managed to do that with this Javascript:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('messages');
  elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
}, 100);
```

But with this, the user can't scroll upwards at all, it is always pushing them back down to the bottom of the div. What I want to happen is if the user is already at the bottom of the div, then when a new message appears it scrolls them to the bottom of the div. BUT if the user is NOT at the bottom of the div then leave them alone until they scroll to the bottom.

Here's the jQuery that updates the div:

```
window.onload = function(){

            setInterval(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "get.php",
                    type: "GET",
                    success: function(output){
                       $("div#messages").html("<p>" + output + "</p>");

                    }
                });
            }, 500);

        }
```

Then the div itself is just empty from the start: `<div id="messages"></div>`

Here's the CSS if you need it:

```
#messages {
    width: 700px;
    height: 250px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    overflow: auto;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Both jQuery and Javascript will work for this, I'm not restricted to using one or the other.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`scrollTop`, at maximum scroll, will be equal to the `scrollHeight` minus `offsetHeight` of the element. This is because the `offsetHeight` is included in the `scrollHeight`.

Setting `scrollTop` to `scrollHeight` works because the browser automatically adjusts the variable to the maximum scroll allowed (`scrollHeight - offsetHeight`).

Here's the logic you should use:

```
if (elem.scrollTop >= (elem.scrollHeight - elem.offsetHeight)) {
    elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
}
```

Just slap the if statement around where you're assigning `elem.scrollTop` to `elem.scrollHeight`

Comment: The use of `>=` protects against the unlikely case that you scroll past the content of the element.

Comment: I know I'm supposed to avoid comments like this, but Thanks for the answer AND explanation!

Answer (score -3):

You can do this easily by altering your second code block to the following and removing the first code block.

```
window.onload = function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
          url: "get.php",
          type: "GET",
          success: function(output){

              var elem = document.getElementById('messages');
              var scrollToBottom = false;
              if(elem.scrollTop == elem.scrollHeight){
                   scrollToBottom = true;
              }

              $(elem).html("<p>" + output + "</p>");
              if(scrollToBottom ){
                   elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
              }
        });
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: I'd ask if you have tested this, but seeing as not only the logic doesn't make sense, but you're also using the wrong operator for comparison, I'll assume you didn't.

Comment: scrollTop will never be scrollHeight. You need to subtract the height of the div from scrollTop for this to work as expected.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work, still pushing the user to the bottom of the div even if they are scrolled upward. Also if you would have explained that would have been even better.

Comment: @Soupd'Campbells can you possibly post that as an answer? I understand what you are talking about when you say subtract the height of the div from scrollTop but I don't know where exactly to modify the code. Thanks, I don't know as much jQuery/Javascript as others.