# How to know if AJAX has fetched a new data?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm making a chatting website. I use AJAX to fetch the chat messages ever 2 seconds. I also use a scrollTop: to auto scroll the page upon data load. But i can't seem to figure out how to only auto scroll when a new message has arrived not every 2 seconds.

```
$('.contact').click(function() {
$('.cont').not(this).removeClass('active');
$(this).toggleClass('active');
sendRequest();
function sendRequest(){
var convo_id=document.getElementById("convo_id").value;
 $.ajax({
  cache: false,
  type: "POST",
  url: 'show_chat.php',
  data: ({convo_id: convo_id}),
  success: function(response) {
  $('#chatgoeshere').html(response);
  $(".messages").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "fast");},
    complete: function() {
   // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
   setTimeout(sendRequest, 2000); // The interval set to 5 seconds
   }
   });
   };
   });
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Transform Your server response from simple HTML to object and include the total count of messages in this chat:

```
{ html: "yourHtml", messagesCount: yourMessagesCount }
```

then in the javascript compare old count with received count and if true, update the content

```
if(oldMessages < response.messagesCount)
```

also update the content only if there is new messages, otehrwise you are re-rendering the page and wasting resources if there is nothing new :)

Comment: is there a way to know if the user is already scrolled at the bottom? if the page can only scroll when the user is at the bottom of the screen and not when he is browsing old messages.

Comment: yes there is, please see the answer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24356463/check-if-div-is-scrolled-to-bottom-leave-alone-if-not

Answer (score 0):

in this line

```
success: function(response) {
```

You need to check for the response. if you get some data, you can scroll the page up.

Comment: Yes but data is always being fetched (old chat messages). Is there a way to know whether there is a new data?

Comment: in that case you can compare data with existing data and if its different scroll else don't

Comment: exactly! how do i do that?

Comment: you need to count records in your Functions and compare with the last count.

Answer (score 0):

check if the response is not empty only then add the scroll function

```
if response
{
  $('#chatgoeshere').html(response);
  $(".messages").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "fast");},

}
```